# Service for thumbnail generation from a video 

Tags: video

I want to create a media gallery consisting of images and videos. Now for videos I just want to show images with a play button over it rather than embedding the video. And then open the video after I have clicked on the play button. Some thing like what [this](http://chill.com/) website does. How could this be done. Can I write my own service for it. Or is there any free service which can do it automatically. For example a service from [embed.ly](http://embed.ly). We give the following:

```
(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwdnMcM0NXg&feature=g-all-esi&context=G27cd8c6FAAAAAAAABAA",

    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data).thumbnail_url);
    },
});
```

})()

Comment: have a look at [this](http://embed.ly/docs/explore/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DLM8JhvfoqdA%26feature%3Dg-all-s%26context%3DG23a20a0FAAAAAAAACAA).

Answer (score 0):

Try this [converter](http://easyhtml5video.com/) which gives you thumbnails for the videos so that you can show the image of the videos as a gallery.

Comment: The process should be automated.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what i would do :

With jQuery , give a class to the images , a keep the media link somewhere , like in a data attribute :

```
<img src='img.jpg' data-link='video.mp4' class='video' />
```

then the javascript :

```
$(.video).click(function(event){
var link = $(this).data("link");
$(this).replaceWith("<video src='"+link+"'/>");
});
```

Comment: This is the easy part But how do i get the image which should be shown as thumbnail.

Comment: you need to take a screenshot of the video you cant do that in javascript.

Comment: Have a look at [Embedly](http://embed.ly/docs/explore/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DLM8JhvfoqdA%26feature%3Dg-all-s%26context%3DG23a20a0FAAAAAAAACAA). I would like to have this kind of service but free ;)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with code , you want a service that does the thumbnail generation online , how is it related to jQuery ?

Comment: Right most probably I have stated the question in a wrong way. Thanks for pointing out.